# "make uninstall" target for drcsim

Tags: drcsim

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

When compiling drcsim from source, there is not "uninstall" make target, which makes uninstalling the compiled version more cumbersome than it should be. Of course, one can always create a little helper script, but it seems unnecessary to make each user find their own way of uninstalling.
Or am I missing some obvious option here? If not, I'll open a ticket on the drcsim bitbucket.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1496/%22make-uninstall%22-target-for-drcsim/) by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/9/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 473 on 2013-02-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You're right; the `uninstall` target missing from drcsim.  Please file a ticket and we'll add it (we'll add it faster if the ticket includes a patch, perhaps copying the CMake code from gazebo).

---

Originally posted by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) with karma: 1414 on 2013-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0